# Material-ui not working in Safari only with Gulp-compass

Tags: gulp, reactjs, gulp-compass

I am using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) lib for react components, the scss port [material-ui-sass](https://github.com/gpbl/material-ui-sass)

See the following screenshot on Safari (Both mobile and desktop). They are working in Chrome, Firefox, even Opera, but just not in Safari.

[image]

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.compass({
      css: '.tmp/styles',
      sass: 'app/styles'
    }));
});
```

Does anyone have a hint on where the error might be? I thought it was the autoprefixer not working, but the prefixes for webkit are added. Very confused at the moment. Any help would be appreciated. The core issue seems to be not running autoprefixer after .pipe($.compass({
          css: '.tmp/styles',
          sass: 'app/styles'
        }));

I tried without success with following code:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.compass({
      css: '.tmp/styles',
      sass: 'app/styles'
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 5 versions']
    }));
});
```

Comment: Did you try opening an issue on one of the project sites? You'd need to add actual examples though as it seems likely it has nothing to do with the packaging of your CSS and JavaScript files

Comment: And why did you tag it with angular and materialize?

Comment: @WiredPrairie mostly hoping for people who have knowledge of Material CSS to pitch some ideas on this type of issue, since I don't know enough about it.

Comment: also already opened issue on the project as well.

Comment: But, what's the programming question here as you don't have any details about how to reproduce the issue. Could you add a JSFiddle or equivalent that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: i will try, will take a little more time to take it out of the current project and isolate these elements. I just fixed one of the issues by adding -webkit- prefix, so i think it might be just a matter of adding these prefixes

Comment: @WiredPrairie Updated the question now. It has nothing to do with CSS or a JSFiddle type of issue. It is only a how to use gulp properly question now.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The issue was with not having autoprefixer ran with gulp.dest. A silly beginner gulp mistake.